# Oracle Fusion Middleware Datasource getting suspended frequently

Tags: weblogic, datasource, soa, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware

We are using Oracle SOA Suite 11g and the Datasource that is used by the BPEL server goes to suspended mode frequently.

As the SOA datasource goes suspended, all the managed servers that use this datasource get too  busy trying to connect to the DB and cause high CPU and hence making the server unresponsive.

Anyone experienced this issue and have a solution? We have already posted this in Oracle forums and created a support ticket but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we've been using the modified setting for a while and we dont see the issue anymore. Looks like changing the SyncMaxTimeout from default 45 to 240 worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios that could cause this to happen. A good starting point will be to enable the JDBC debug logs to see what's causing the suspension.

Comment: Thanks for yout response. 
we have reported this issue to oracle and they suggested to increase the syncMaxTimeout which is at very low by default. we will check if this change works.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's an interesting suggestion since they usually ask for a decrease in the timeout period. Keep us posted on the progress :-)